# Android DateUtils flags explained

Tags: android, android-dateutils

I am using `getRelativeTimeSpanString (long time, long now, long minResolution, int flags)` to calculate a relative date. The docs say that `flags` is "a bit mask of formatting options, such as FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE or FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE". However, there are about a dozen other flags defined in `DateUtils`, and the only ones with any description at all are deprecated.

1. Is it possible to use any of the other flags with `getRelativeTimeSpanString()`?
2. What is the actual behavior of the other flags?
3. Specifically, I'd like to come out with things like `5d`, `6h`, and `2m`, but I'm not seeing anything that looks like it does that. Will I have to roll my own?